# Parent of session object: request or application

Tags: java, session, web-applications

Its an interview question: What is the parent of session object?

As per scope(in image below) my answer is : application  [image]

But, the answer was given as request.. as we can access session object from request context by request.getSession() method.

I am not able to understand how a single request can be parent of whole user session?

Sorry if i am breaking any question guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no parent-child relationship at all here. At least in OO parlance, parent-child relationship is said to be present when there is inheritance involved. Neither Application nor Request fall on the inheritance tree of Session.

So, I would say that the interview question itself is a bit weird :)

Comment: I agree. You didn't want _that_ job.

Answer (score 1):

The question is strange to me because we don't have relationship in OO meaning. It's only owner (creator) here. We have Http Request implements HttpServletRequest which has:

```
/**
 * Returns the current session associated with this request,
 * or if the request does not have a session, creates one.
 */
public HttpSession getSession();
```

This method will create new object if doesn't exist else it returns created Session Object so if someone can be in parent-relationship, that can be only Request - but in my opinion we can't say that, better question would be: "which class manage http object?" or "which class has http object?"